Rectangular texture issue -- OpenGL C++
I'm having a bit of trouble with using rectangular textures on my nvidia 3060 GPU. Everything works well when using square textures.
The small GLSL compute shader code and small C++ code can be found at: https://github.com/sjhalayka/light_blocking_asymmetric
I've done my best to make the code as simple as possible. Is there a small bug, or a feature that I'm missing? Thanks for your time and expertise.
Rectangular texture (undesired, sheared lighting):

Square texture (desired lighting):


The "rectangular" image looks like the height is being used for the width for drawing the lit area. So potentially height and width are being transposed somewhere. On a square texture if height and width are swapped it won't matter.

Thank you for your guidance and time. I ended up going with square power-of-two textures so that I can do a tile-based renderer. I thank you for pointing out my error.

I cannot figure out how to fix this bug elegantly. Instead, I just made it so that rectangular textures are made square by padding with black pixels before computing, and then cropping the output from square back to rectangular.

